# Regular sequence in local rings

Tags: commutative-algebra

Assume that $(R,m)$ is a local ring and $J\subset I$ are proper ideals of $R$. 
If $I/J$ is generated by regular sequence in $R/J$, I want to show that $$J\cap I^t=JI^{t-1}\    \forall t\geq1.$$